# Cocoa Bindings: binding each menu item of a NSPopUpButton, so that it can be enabled/disabled individually

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, cocoa-bindings

It’s been a very long time since I’ve working with *Cocoa Bindings*, so my knowledge isn’t very fresh.

I am trying to connect up a `NSPopUpButton` so that each menu item can be enabled or disabled separately. I have connected up the `content` binding to an array controller that has two properties: `localizedName` and `enabled`. These represent the names and enabled status of each menu item that will be shown.

I’ve also connected up the `contentValues` binding so that it is bound to the `arrangedObjects.localizedName` property.

Now I’m stumped. There is an `enabled` binding but it seems to connect to the entire popup button, not the menu items.

Is there a way to connect to the enabled property of each individual menu item? in the same way as is possible with `NSTableView`?

Thanks in advance.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity: While I haven't found out how to link to the enabled attribute of the popup menu button's `NSMenuItem`, I have found out that `NSPopupButton` does not handle disabled menu items anyway.. it just does nothing. The `state` and the `hidden` attributes`both work fine, however, so I ended up just hiding the non-selectable entries via the`NSMenuDelegate` instead.